# Serial port listening through windows services in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created a windows service to listen the serial port inputs,below is my code but Im getting an error like missing assembly, I googled it but few article says to add `System.WIndows.Forms` Namespace,Even i added that Im getting the same error

> Error 1   'VisionSystemService.VisionSystemService' does not contain a
>   definition for 'BeginInvoke' and no extension method 'BeginInvoke'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'VisionSystemService.VisionSystemService' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 public partial class VisionSystemService : ServiceBase
    {
        SerialPort _SerialPort;
        private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

        public VisionSystemService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _SerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            _SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _SerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
            _SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _SerialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            _SerialPort.Open();

        }
        void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            string data = _SerialPort.ReadExisting();
            this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {




        }


        private void si_DataReceived(string data)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Typically BeginInvoke is used for cross thread updates to UI elements such as feedback of a long running task to the user form. This is a service however and does not have any UI to display output. you might rather consider using logging for this?

Comment: logging? I'm not getting you .@AdriaanStander.

Comment: The usage you have is typical of UI updates, whereas I would think you wish to process that data as it comes in. What I meant by logging is to rather use a logging framework for services if you wish to see output of your applications workings

Answer (score 0):

Your getting this error because neither your VisionSystemService class or ServiceBase have a method called BeginInvoke.  I recommend to just invoke your delegate.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.